# Block access to other private IP addresses on CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, firewall

I want to limit the access of CentOS device in LAN.

For example, it's local IP is 192.168.1.2 and I want to block all traffic from this device to other local IPs from 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.254 except itself while keeping the internet access active.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: add more details to the question

Comment: @Alex Let me know what detail you need. I am new to this channel.

Comment: @discover CentOS is being discontinued so you might better consider using Rocky or Alma linux if you want to stay on rpm based distro's.. Now to answer your question. What CentOS release and are you trying to achieve this using iptables or firewalld?  I assume you want the latter.  If so, can you show the output of `firewall-cmd --list-all-zones`

Comment: @ValentinBajrami https://codefile.io/f/KcYFI3hn2ohyS56P2ZXw
Please check it.

Comment: Do the other users of this device have root privileges? If so there's little point using iptables because it's trivial for someone to bypass. Instead place the firewall restriction outside the device

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add requested information to your question instead of using external sites. What do you want to achieve by blocking the traffic? Add details about your network infrastructure.